# Why didn't the Black Order attack Thor in the Battle of Wakanda?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War* we see the Black Order overcome Thor from a most likely earlier battle. But when he returns they don't even seem to attack him at all even though he runs towards them and practically breaks Wakanda. Why is that whilst he was in plain sight of them?

Comment: Thor didn't have Stormbreaker in the beginning.

Comment: I think the primary reason is that Thor was holding this really powerful ax and the Black Order members were like 'uhh...I'm going to fight someone else on this battlefield'.

Answer (score 5):

Because they were preoccupied fighting some of the other Avengers. You have to remember the main plan was to keep the main battle busy whilst the Black Order, specifically Corvus, retrieved the Mind Stone from Vision. The battle, if anything, was a secondary objective. Of the survivors and none traitors of the Black Order we have:

#### Cull Obsidian

After Thor lands he is initially fighting with Black Panther before going to attack Bruce in the Hulkbuster suit to help out Corvus with fighting Vision. During this fight with Banner he is thrown into the energy barrier and killed.

#### Corvus Glaive

Before Thor lands and afterwards he is busy fighting Vision and later Banner in the Hulkbuster armour as mentioned above. His sole objective in the whole battle was to get the Mind Stone from Vision as we saw earlier with him sneaking behind enemy lines.

#### Proxima Midnight

She was initially leading the battle but once on the field she targeted the biggest Avengers threat, or one at least on par with Thor: Wanda. However, she was ambushed by Black Widow and Okoye into a three versus one fight which she eventually lost and was killed.

So simply none of the surviving members engaged Thor because their priorities were of the Mind Stone or other high value targets and they simply didn't get the chance.

Comment: And Ebony Maw is busy being dead

Comment: @Valorum Yeah I find it's hard to fight Norse gods if you're currently a popsicle in space.